# How to implement graphQL sub-query

Tags: graphql

I'm having a block trying to figure out the syntax for a query condition that seems like it would be a pretty common one.

The typedef below stores an ID value for the agent who represents an Author, in a one-agent-to-many (authors) relationship.  I'd like to extract the name of the agent at the same time I'm getting details from the Author schema.

```
type Author {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String
    middleInitial: String
    lastName: String
    posts: [Post]
    agent: ID
  }
```

So the enclosing query (returning a list of all Authors) looks like this:

```
{
  authors {
    firstName
    lastName
    agent
    }
}
```

This gives me back the Agent's ID.  How can I use that same query to fetch the agent's name, from a typedef similar to the one above?

Answer (score 4):

```
type Agent {
    id: ID!
    name: String
}

type Author {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String
    middleInitial: String
    lastName: String
    posts: [Post]
    agent: Agent
}

// Query
 {
   authors {
     firstName
     lastName
     agent {
         name
      }
    } 
  }
```

Comment: This is the precise "workaround" I adopted, but I was thinking it would be easier to use cursor-type IDs in a typedef and then use them as an index to another object.  I may have been mistaken.

Comment: I don't think this is a workaround.. This is the right way to do this

Comment: So it can't be done via an index "ID?"  So many of the sample schemas out there use that method, I figured there had to be a way to resolve it in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

The query would look like this. I'm not sure what your Agent typedef is like, but you get the idea

```
type Author {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String
    middleInitial: String
    lastName: String
    posts: [Post]
    agent: {
        id
        name
        ...other_agent_properties
    }
}
```

Comment: I mistakenly said one-to-one; each author has an agent, but each agent has many authors.